# Gitlab message when trying to merge "The source branch (release/v1.2.3) is N commits behind the target branch (master)"

Tags: gitlab

We manage source code in gitlab and have the following branch strategy :

- we pull feature/xyz branches from develop ; merge them back into develop once validated
- when milestone is completed, we pull release/v1.2.3 from develop and merge it into master

At that stage, we have the following message ("The source branch is N commits behind the target branch) and I cannot use the gitlab 'merge' button.
Anyhow, I can pull branches from origin repository to my local repository, do the merge with command lines (with no conflict), then push back onto the origin repository and then finish delivery process.

My question is why do I have such message ? what does it mean ? How can I fix ?

I already tried to merge master into develop after a delivery to be sure that develop = master (even if gitlab compare functionality told me this was the case) ; but this doen't change anything, I have same message at next release.

Comment: Edit : We are on Gitlab 14.10

Comment: I meant 15.5 *restored* that message which was present in 14.x, but disappeared for some reason in 15.0.

Answer (score 0):

> why do I have such message ? what does it mean ? How can I fix ?

That seems to be from GitLab 15.5 (Oct. 2022) and [issue 368295](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/368295).
[Issue 378060](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/378060) mentions the notion of "divergence":

> When using "merge commit" merge method, the commit divergence count does not display if there is divergence between source and target branches. It only seems to display if a file has been changed in the target branch in one of the diverged commits, that is also being changed in the source branch of the MR.

To avoid said "divergence", whenever you are doing a merge request, it is best if the source branch you want to merge is rebased first on top of the target branch.

That way: you won't have any conflict, and the merge of the source branch (now on top of the target branch) will be a trivial one.

---

> As discussed, Rebase button is not working on GitLab (and anyhow, I rather us the command line to be sure about what I do). Could you please give me the exact command line(s) to rebase `release/v1.2.3` on top of `master`?
> (I guess this start with `git checkout master` and then rebasing on it, and then I `git push master` onto `origin` repo ; but I am not sure about what's in between ;-) )

Yes, there is a local step, in order to rebase and then push `release/v1.2.3` (you never push `master`: it is protected for a reason)

```bash
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repository
git fetch
git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base develop release/v1.2.3) release/v1.2.3
git push --force
```

That will update the MR in progress (the one for merging `release/v1.2.3` to `master`)

Comment: I had to push a small release this morning and faced the same issue =>  "Request to merge release/v1.102.1 into master The source branch is 190 commits behind the target branch". I tried to click the blue button 'Rebase' aside of "Merge blocked: the source branch must be rebased onto the target branch.". But gitlab answers by "Something went wrong. Please try again"

Comment: That is where rebasing just your commits on top of origin/master will help. Local rebase + push --force. The MR will be updated automatically.

Comment: As discussed, Rebase button is not working on Gitlab (and anyhow, i rather us the command line to be sure about what I do). Could you please give me the exact command line(s) to rebase release/v1.2.3 on top of master (I guess this start with git checkout master and then rebasing on it, and then i git push master onto origin repo ; but i'm not sure about what's in between ;-) ).

Comment: @EdouardLOISEAU I have edited the answer with the relevant local step.